# how does javascript async works with cycles?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I'm trying to understand how async working in javascript. and i cant handle 1 thing, that create async: async function with other promises generators and callbacks, or webAPI?

Here's a code. If i'am using settimeout function all works correctly but if i using a cycle something works unpredictable; then i using settimeout result showing 1 by 1 with timeout, but with a cycle result showing at the same time

```
function timeout(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
async function sleep() {
  console.time("abc");
  await timeout(3000);
  console.timeEnd("abc");
}

sleep();

console.time();
var z = 1;
for (let i = 1; i < 10000; i++) {
  for (let j = 1; j < 10000; j++) {
    z *= j;
  }
  z *= i;
}
console.timeEnd();


//second var

function second(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    var z = 1;
    for (let i = 1; i < 50000; i++) {
      for (let j = 1; j < 50000; j++) {
        z *= j;
      }
      z *= i;
    }
    resolve();
  });
}

// function timeout(ms) {
//   return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
// }
async function sleep() {
  console.time("abc");
  await second();
  console.timeEnd("abc");
}

sleep();

console.time();
var z = 1;
for (let i = 1; i < 10000; i++) {
  for (let j = 1; j < 10000; j++) {
    z *= j;
  }
  z *= i;
}
console.timeEnd();
```

//first result showing 1 by 1 with timeout

default: 932.822998046875ms

abc: 3000.555908203125ms

//second result showing at the same time

default: 913.716064453125ms

abc: 4396.77490234375ms

Comment: Execution order of asych functions cannot be guaranteed. And, precise timing cannot be guaranteed.  Javascript environment is executing much more than just your block of code. So various async functions are queuing up waiting for execution. (1) The only thing for sure about `setTimeout(1000)` is that it will be *at least* 1000ms before it is executed. (2) To guarantee async execution order use Promises. (3) Promise execution order has nothing to do with any other async functions or other Promise objects; other async functions might execute between the promise-chain-functions.

Comment: Um, what did you expect? And why?

Comment: @JonasWilms i expected that in second var console.time go 1 by 1 with some timeout, coz async cycle more than sync. but it goes in same time

Answer (score -1):

The normal `for` loops that you are using do not wait for Promise's to resolve before moving to the next iteration. You can either use a library like bluebird, which is optimized for promise handling, especially with collections, or use the `for (i in arr){}` loop.

Comment: Um ... just no?

Comment: no thats right. go ahead and try to resolve promises on every value of an array with async/await and me know how that works out.

Comment: @michaelOssig can u pls give me some code to show how it is?

Comment: @IlyaGirsenok theres a good article on this here https://codeburst.io/asynchronous-code-inside-an-array-loop-c5d704006c99